# WinTV-HVR/Linux Me TV

Tags: tv, tv-tuner

I found on the product  website how to get the `WinTV-HVR 950`(is a TV tuner that allows you to watch FTA TV on computer)   to work in Linux. I followed the link but all I get is a Text document. I tried several commands in the Terminal  but nothing.

Do you have any more suggestions? Tried `ME TV`(An App I found in Ubuntu app center) and didn't work.

Comment: Please edit your question to include more detail of what this product is, what you have attempted, including links that you may have used. As it stands, your question lacks enough detail to offer useful suggestions.

Comment: Is this a USB device? Please edit your question to include: lsusb Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is a USB device and what is Isusb

Comment: Open Terminal and type in `lsusb` which will list the USB devices connected to your system.

Comment: Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2232:1029  
is wat it came up with and that is my trackball mouse

Comment: Uhm, according to the [Hauppauge website](http://www.hauppauge.com/site/support/support_hvr950.html), your device is not officially supported under any flavor of Linux. There is an experimental LinuxTV driver [found here](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Hauppauge_WinTV-HVR-950) for which installation instructions for the firmware are found at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I looked at the Hauppauge website be for buying and it said there where some drivers and gave me the web site toget them,but all I got when tried to download was a tex doc.

Comment: Hauppauge does not list any Linux drivers - they only have drivers for Windows which **will not work** on your system. You will need to [go to the LinuxTV](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Hauppauge_WinTV-HVR-950) site I linked previously and follow the instructions there to download and install a driver for Ubuntu. If you found links to Linux driver somewhere other than the Hauppague website, then please post that link so we can see what it is, as apparently it is not working for you.

Comment: Linux TV is the link I found on the Hauppauga site I tried to down load drivers and go a text doc that I could not make heads or tails of

Answer (score 0):

Hauppague does not provide Linux drivers for the WinTV-HVR 950. You will need to use the experimental Linux drivers from [LinuxTV](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Hauppauge_WinTV-HVR-950#Firmware). To condense the installation instructions from LinuxTV, install the firmware and driver support for the device, this procedure *should* work.

Open a Terminal session with Cntl-Alt-F1. Enter the following:

```
cd ~/Downloads

wget http://www.steventoth.net/linux/xc5000/HVR-12x0-14x0-17x0_1_25_25271_WHQL.zip

unzip -j HVR-12x0-14x0-17x0_1_25_25271_WHQL.zip Driver85/hcw85bda.sys

./extract_xc3028.pl

cp xc3028-v27.fw /lib/firmware

wget http://linuxtv.org/downloads/drivers/linux-media-2014-03-14-ed97a6f.tar.bz2

tar xvjf linux-media-2014-03-14-ed97a6f.tar.bz2

./configure

make

sudo make install
```

You will probably have to do a system restart for the firmware and driver to fully load.

As this is an experimental third-party driver, there is no support other than through LinuxTV and there is no guarantee that this will work with your system.

Comment: I keep trying it and I got ERROR 404 not found

Comment: Which `wget` statement throws the 404 error?

Comment: the 1st 1 www.steventoth.net/...............

Comment: The `wget` statement is right - just tested on my machine and it downloaded. Try just using the URL in your browser and see if it downloads.